# Highlight all occurrences of string - case insensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

On this [page](http://beta.fray.it/support) I want to search for a word in the text and highlight all occurrences. If, for example, I look for "front end" than I want all occurrences of "Front end" to be highlighted. With the code below I do highlight them but the occurrences's upper case character is also replaced. Can you fix this? here's my code:

this makes jQuery contains case insensitive

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

and this is the code that highlights by replacing

```
$('input[value="Zoeken"]').click(function(){
    $('.section').html(function (i, str) {
        yellowspan = new RegExp('<span style="background-color: #FFFF00">' ,"g"); 
        empty = "";
        return str.replace(yellowspan, empty);
    });

    $('.section').html(function (i, str) {
        endspan = new RegExp("</span>" ,"g"); 
        empty = "";
        return str.replace(endspan, empty);
    });

    var string = $('input[placeholder="Zoeken"]').val();                    
    $('.section:contains("' + string + '")').each(function(index, value){
        $(this).html(function (i, str) {
            simpletext = new RegExp(string,"gi"); 
            yellowtext = "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>" + string + "</span>";
            return str.replace(simpletext, yellowtext);
        });
    });
});
```

the problematic code is on the last `html()` function

Comment: What's the problem of your code ? Have you tried to understand what doen't work ?

Comment: I alter the jQuery contains so as to find all occurences of a string whether upper or lower case. Then I look for any span tags used for highlighting already in place and removes them. Lastly I highlight all new occurences by replacing their text with the string searched. BUT as I say above, this replaces uppercase characters that these occurences may have with lower case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

replace

```
simpletext = new RegExp(string,"gi"); 
yellowtext = "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>" + string + "</span>";
return str.replace(simpletext, yellowtext);
```

with

```
simpletext = new RegExp("(" + string + ")","gi"); 
return str.replace(simpletext, "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>$1</span>")
```

the extra parens in `new Regexp()` capture the value found. the $1 in `str.replace` inserts the captured value

Comment: PHP equivalent:
return preg_replace('/('. $searchText . ')/i', '<span style="background-color: #FFFF00:>$1</span>', $foundString);